# Write a program to check it the two strings are balanced

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program to check it the two strings are balanced. For example, `s1` and `s2` are balanced if all the characters in the `s1` are present in `s2`. My compiler showing correct, but while evaluating in website it's showing error in balance one while unbalance working.

```
def balance(s1,s2):
    flag=True

    if (len(s1) == len(s2)):
        for i in s1:
            if i in s2:
                continue
            else:
                flag = False

        return flag

s1 = input()
s2 = input()

if balance(s1, s2) == True:
    print("Balance")
else:
    print("Unbalanced")
```

Comment: "_s1 and s2 are balanced if all the characters in the s1 are present in s2_" So if `s1 = 'foo'` and `s2 = 'foot'`, the strings are balanced? Or do the characters in s2 also have to be present in s1? Please clarify your question. Add some examples if balanced and unbalanced strings.

Answer (score 1):

### Python program to check if two strings are balanced

#### What does it mean for two strings to be balanced?

Two strings are balanced if they have the same set of characters, regardless of their order or frequency. For example, "abc" and "cba" are balanced, but "abc" and "ab" are not.

#### How to write a python program to check if two strings are balanced?

One possible way to write a python program to check if two strings are balanced is to use a **set** data structure. A set is a collection of unique elements that supports operations like union, intersection, and difference. We can use a set to store the characters of each string and then compare them using the **==** operator. If the sets are equal, then the strings are balanced. Otherwise, they are not.

Here is an example of a python program that implements this logic:

```py
# Define a function that takes two strings as parameters
def are_balanced(s1, s2):
  # Convert each string to a set of characters
  # Compare the sets using the == operator
  return set(s1) == set(s2)

# Test the function with some examples
print(are_balanced("abc", "cba")) # True
print(are_balanced("abc", "ab")) # False
print(are_balanced("hello", "olleh")) # True
print(are_balanced("hello", "world")) # False
```

#### Why is this a good solution?

This solution is good because it is simple, efficient, and easy to understand. It uses a built-in data structure and a common operator to perform the task. It also works for any pair of strings, regardless of their length or case.

Comment: Great answer. Many persons answer these type of questions with a quick code-only answer, but there should be more answers like this, that provide more context and explanation (as well as some code to demonstrate that). Well done! Keep on going like this. I think the huge fonts were a bit distracting though, so I reduced them a bit. I hope you'll do the same in your next posts :-)

Comment: One less positive thing though: the question states that _s1 and s2 are balanced if all the characters in the s1 are present in s2_. Your code assumes the the other way around as well. I'm not sure if that's what OP meant (question is unclear IMHO). Maybe there's a standard definition for "balanced strings" (I couldn't find one though), but if not, then strictly you did not answer the question...

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary that the 2 strings are of same length.

For eg: `s1 = "123"` `s2 = "12345"` The characters of `s1` exist in `s2` but they are not of the same length

Edit the code to:

```
def balance(s1,s2):

    flag=True

    for i in s1:

        if i in s2:

            pass

        else:

            flag=False

    return flag

s1=input()

s2=input()

if balance(s1,s2)==True:

    print("Balance")

else:

print("Unbalanced")
```

There should be no if condition at the start

Answer (score 0):

It's way easier using `set`

```
def balance(s1, s2):
    return set(s1) == set(s2)


s1 = input()
s2 = input()
if balance(s1, s2):
    print("Balance")
else:
    print("Unbalanced")
```